# How to switch between syntastic error window and editor window

Tags: vim-windows, plugin-syntastic

I am new to vim and currently learning as well.
I just started using syntastic in vim to lint my code.

I have set following vars in my `.vimrc` file:

```
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

If any error comes error window gets open, and show the list of errors.
I just want to know is there any way to switch betweeb opened error window and current window.

Also is there any keystroke which I can use to move to next and prev error? (not by using `:lnext` and `:lprev`)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You could map something to `lprev` and `lnext`.

Comment: will you please explain me how to to do that? I am quite new to it. Thanks

Comment: You don't.  Well, you _can_ do it, but it's better to stay in the editor window.  See the [FAQ](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic#faqlnext).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To switch between two windows see [`:h window-move-cursor`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window-move-cursor). Here you'll use <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>, since the windows are horizontally split.

Now to use `:lnext` and `:lprev` more easily you could use a mapping as suggested by @muru. To do so add something like that to your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <c-n> :lnext<CR>
```

This line will make <kbd>Ctrl-n</kbd> execute `:lnext` in normal mode. See [`:h mapping`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapping).

Of course change the mapped keys (here `<c-n>`) to whatever fits your needs.